# jQuery mobile footer text formatting

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add some text to a jQuery mobile footer like this:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="footer">
<p style='text-align:center;'>This text should not be blurred like this</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-page .ui-footer {
  background: #3B5DA1 !important;
  color:#FFFFFF !important;
  font-family:verdana !important;
  font-size:10px !important;
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

But as you can see on the image below, the text shows all blurred. 
I'm stuck with this, as I am not able to make the footer text appear nice and clean.
Thanks

[image: jquery mobile]

Comment: Nowhere in your code it says it should have a shadow, so I'd be more worried about removing the original source of this p tag being shadowed or you'll have to start specifying text-shadow:none every time you create a <p> </p>

Comment: @LOTUSMS, text shadowing is included in the jQuery Mobile CSS which is used to enhance the pages. The OP can either override this where needed or change the jQuery Theme to not apply the shadowing.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be a better solution than adding text-shadow:none to the footer. It is better to initialize the p tag as plain as possible in a reset and then use classes to style as needed. It will help avoid !important hacks

Comment: like what ezanker says what I do is creating a separate css file and load it after jQuery mobile's css library and override them as I want. Because after all they are just css styling.

Comment: that looks like an Iphone, so try adding this ---  html {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
} --- source http://files.christophzillgens.com/webkit-font-smoothing.html -- also try different fonts

Comment: Thank you all. text-shado:none; seemed to do the trick.